# How to get values from multi-level JSON using javascript without knowing the keys

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have the following json:

```
{"sensors": 
        {"-KqYN_VeXCh8CZQFRusI": 
            {"bathroom_temp": 16,
             "date": "02/08/2017", 
             "fridge_level": 8,
             "kitchen_temp": 18, 
             "living_temp": 17, 
             "power_bathroom": 0, 
             "power_bathroom_value": 0, 
             "power_kit_0": 0
        }, 
        "-KqYPPffaTpft7B72Ow9": 
            {"bathroom_temp": 20, 
             "date": "02/08/2017", 
             "fridge_level": 19, 
             "kitchen_temp": 14, 
             "living_temp": 20, 
             "power_bathroom": 0, 
             "power_bathroom_value": 0
        },  
        "-KqYPUld3AOve8hnpnOy": 
            {"bathroom_temp": 23, 
             "date": "02/08/2017", 
             "fridge_level": 40, 
             "kitchen_temp": 11, 
             "living_temp": 10, 
             "power_bathroom": 1, 
             "power_bathroom_value": 81, 
        }
    }
}
```

I am reading it from a file using the following python file :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, url_for
from firebase import firebase
import os




firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://my-firebase-db-958b1.firebaseio.com/', None)
result = firebase.get('/Dublin-Ireland', None)
print "\n Json file created!"


with open ('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(result, outfile)


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    with open('data.txt') as f:
        s = f.read()

    return render_template("homepage.html" , nameTxt = s)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I can pass the json data from the python file to the javascript. After parsing, i'm able to see all the values using JSON.Stringify. But, i'm not able to get one value at a time. What i'm trying to do is to save each key in a file of its own(eg. bathroom_temp, date, fridge_level, etc...) and append the values as the json gets updated in a periodic manner. So that, later on i can just get the data of whatever key i need and plot a line graph using the data. For example, the bathroom_temp file should contain "16, 20, 23", and this can be used to plot a graph.

The following is my javascript code:

```
<script>
      var test = JSON.parse({{ nameTxt|tojson }});
      for(key in test)
      {
          if(test.hasOwnProperty(key))
          {
              var value = test[key];
              alert(JSON.stringify(value, null, 4));

           }
       }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generalize something like:

```
for(key in test['sensors']) {
  var sensor = test['sensors'][key];
  console.log(sensor['bathroom_temp']);
}
```